# Recover from sonarrunner leaving DB in inconsistent state

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

Sonar maven plugin run has failed due to lack of memory. I was trying to run it against one module to debug something...

```
[INFO] [16:16:07.709] Execute PMD 5.4.0 done: 10861 ms
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:07 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-30T16:16:08+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 76M/953M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/usr/share/maven3/lib/wagon-http-2.6-shaded.jar
[SNIP...]
constituent[39]: file:/usr/share/maven3/conf/logging/
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Now, when I try to run sonar on all modules it tells me: `The project 'foo:module1' is already defined in SonarQube but not as a module of project 'foo:aggregator'`

But when I go to sonar:

- there is no project `foo:module1` on the list of all projects
- when I open `http://sonar.example/dashboard/index/foo:module1` it shows the `module1` as a component of `foo:aggregator`
- I see `module1` listed in "Project Permissions" view

I tried running the analysis to completion hoping it will add the project, so that I can remove it later, but I got:

```
[INFO] [17:17:17.805] Execute decorators...
[WARN] [17:17:33.408] Too many components under resource 'module1'. DSM will not be displayed.
[INFO] [17:17:33.526] Store results in database
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:19 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-30T17:17:33+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 57M/1044M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.5:sonar (default-cli) on project module1: Unable to save file sources:
[ERROR] ### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '34503e95-81ac-40bb-a73c-60325a11088c' for key 'file_sources_file_uuid_uniq'
[ERROR] ### The error may involve org.sonar.core.source.db.FileSourceMapper.insert-Inline
[ERROR] ### The error occurred while setting parameters
[ERROR] ### SQL: INSERT INTO file_sources (project_uuid, file_uuid, created_at, updated_at, binary_data, line_hashes, data_hash, src_hash)     VALUES (?, ?, ?,     ?, ?, ?,     ?, ?)
[ERROR] ### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '34503e95-81ac-40bb-a73c-60325a11088c' for key 'file_sources_file_uuid_uniq'
```

How do I 'delete' the `foo:module1` from sonar so that I can run the analysis on `foo:aggregator`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I could do was to remove the `module1` using the *Bulk Deletion* 
That took all the module's data with it.

So apparently you can hose your Sonar data just by executing the runner on a maven submodule. Way to go!